# Use grep, filter or each to perform intersection of 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to merge 2 arrays efficiently in JQuery. Essentially I should merge the 2 arrays but if there is a 'element collision' array1 takes precedence. I think what I am doing is a intersection where array1 has precidence?

What isn't clear to me is if I should use 2 nested `$.each()` statements to achieve my goal or if I can use `$.grep()` or `$.filter()` to achieve my goals in a more efficient manor? Any advice?

Below explains my objective in code:

```
var customMenuBtns = [
    {
        name: 'addText',
        callback: ...
    },
    {
        name: 'trash',
        callback: function() {   // My custom trash callback
            console.log("Custom trash");
        }
    }
];


var defMenuBtns = [
    {
        name: 'addComponent',
        callback: ...
    },
    {
        name: 'trash',
        callback: ...
    }
];



// Merge customMenuBtns and defMenuBtns. 
// If both arrays contain a button with the same name; we discard the 
// defMenuBtns and keep the customMenuBtns

// So in the above example; after merging we should have

var menuBtns = [
    {
        name: 'addText',
        callback: ...
    },
    {
        name: 'trash',
        callback: function() {   // My custom trash callback
            console.log("Custom trash");
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'addComponent',
        callback: ...
    }
];
```

Comment: Would you be ok with a non-jquery solution?

Comment: @aduss yes as long as its efficient

Comment: Do the buttons have to have that order after being merged? What if the trash button is before the addComponent button?

Comment: @KevBot That is a good question. My solution assumes order does not matter, that could be fixed.

Comment: @aduss and @kevBot yes I want to preserve the order of `customMenuBtns` and append the other array to the end.

Comment: An "intersection" would be keeping only elements that are common to both arrays. You want more of a custom "union".

Comment: @JakeM I edited my solution to maintain order. Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A non jquery solution that should work and preserve order. You may want to add some 'check for property name' steps, depending on how confident you are that a name element will exist.

```
var merge = function (arr1, arr2) {

    var i, outObj = {}, keys = {};
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i += 1) {
        outObj[arr2[i].name] = arr2[i];
        keys[arr2[i].name] = [i, 2];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i += 1) {
        outObj[arr1[i].name] = arr1[i];
        keys[arr1[i].name] = [i, 1];
    }

    keys = Object.keys(keys).sort(function (a, b) {
        return keys[a][1] - keys[b][1] || keys[a][0] - keys[b][0];
    });

    return keys.map(function (x) {return outObj[x];})

};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need the function $.extends

```
var menuBtns = $.extend({}, defMenuBtns, customMenuBtns);
```

Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

for more information you can check the jquery documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)
you can use it to merge arrays with object too

I think that here you have a complete example

```
var customMenuBtns = [
    {
        name: 'addText',
        callback: function(){}
    },
    {
        name: 'addComponent',
        callback: function(){}
    },
    {
        name: 'trash',
        callback: function() {   // My custom trash callback
            console.log("Custom trash");
        }
    }
];

var defMenuBtns = [
    {
        name: 'addText',
        callback: function(){}
    },
    {
        name: 'addComponent',
        callback: function(){}
    },
    {
        name: 'trash',
        callback: function(){}
    }
];

var menuBtns = $.extend([], defMenuBtns, customMenuBtns);
console.log(menuBtns);
```

Comment: I do not think this will work since he has arrays not objects and is merging based on the name property of an object inside that array.

Comment: It does not work... It drops the addComponent information. It is merging based on keys, which when you pass in an array is just the indices of the array themselves. At least as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Emiliano thanks for your answer but it looks like the resulting array only has 2 elements not 3. The button `addComponent` isn't there?

Comment: that is just because i use the data provided by jake
if default data will have all options the return will be 3 objects

Comment: check the fiddle now
https://jsfiddle.net/epnsp5sL/1/
the default array must have all object options and then you override your own with $.extends function

Comment: @Emiliano This still does not work... It duplicates the trash function, I think the extend function is just not designed for this.

Comment: @aduss we are seeing differents things I think
I see 3 object
addtext
addcomponent 
and trash the new one

Comment: @Emiliano Really? I am seeing this: [{"name":"addText"},{"name":"trash"},{"name":"trash"}] (functions removed for clarity) You are seeing the correct answer? What browser? Not that that should make a difference in this context...

Comment: maybe is because we are using trivial objects